# How to check if bot is in the same channel as user

Tags: node.js, discord.js

So I am making discord music bot using discord-player and discord.js and I want to check if user calling the command is in the same voice channel as bot. I have tried something like this:

```
const sameChannel = client.voice.connections.find(i => i.channel.id === interaction.member.voice.channel.id);
        if (!sameChannel) return interaction.reply('❌ You are not in the same voice channel!')
```

but I have got an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find')
```

I want to prevent users in other channels to be able to for example skip songs.

Answer (score 0):

I might have a solution. The error message "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find')" means that client.voice.connections is undefined, which suggests that the bot is not properly connected to a voice channel. if this doesn't solve the issue than two solutions: log 'client.voice' to see if it's defined, or you can do:

```
  const sameChannel = client.voice.connections.find(i => i.channel.id === interaction.member.voice.channel.id);
  if (!sameChannel) {
    // Handle error here
  }
} else {
  // Handle error here
}

This uses the optional chaining operator ?. to safely access the connections property of client.voice. If either client.voice or client.voice.connections is undefined, the code will skip calling the find method and will instead execute the error handling code.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found working solution.To get the bot's voice channel id I used: `interaction.guild.members.me.voice.channel.id`.
Here is full code:

```
const channel = interaction.member.voice.channel;
    if(channel.id !== interaction.guild.members.me.voice.channel.id)
        //Handle error here
```